# Android: Application restarts sometimes

Tags: android

I found a strange behavior in my App. When i try to fetch data from the internet with bad wifi signal, i have a couple of exceptions(IOException, SocketException). All this exceptions are handled in the application in try-catch block, but app performance slows, and in one moment application restart. I have a SomeClass extends from Application class where onCreate method calls again after this exceptions.

I haven't got OutOfMemory error in the log, and method onLowMemory of Application didn't call.

Is anybody have any idea about this behavior?

Comment: is there something in the LogCat saying something like "killing process <package name>"?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with the application class, but if you call the application.onCreate method while handling exception, it is supposed to restart your application ... ? or am i too enthusiastic ? post your code it'll be clearer anyway!

Comment: onCreate method calls when application is starting(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()) and i doesn't call this method during exception handling.

Comment: must have misunderstood your question. any additional information - logcat, code - would be useful !

Comment: ERROR/dalvikvm(4082): HeapWorker is wedged: 45563ms spent inside Lorg/apache/harmony/xnet/provider/jsse/OpenSSLSessionImpl;.finalize()V
ERROR/dalvikvm(4082): VM aborting
This is part of log when application crashes.

Comment: check the answer at the bottom http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/cbc96b0bfb79e9c4 it might be a good hint !